# Issues using custom cursor with draggable element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cursor

Ok, so I have a draggable element that is contained by it's parent. I'm trying to add a custom cursor while dragging, including when the cursor moves off of the draggable element itself. And then when dragging stops, on `mouseup`, the cursor should return to `default`.

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="draggable"></div>
</div>
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(window).on("mouseup", function() {
        $("*").removeClass("customcursor");   
    })

    $(".draggable").on("mousedown", function() {
        $("*").addClass("customcursor");
    })

    $(".draggable").draggable({
        containment: "parent",
    });
});
```

---

```
html {
    background: lightblue;
}

body {
    background-color: teal;
}

#container {
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    background-color: black;
}

.draggable {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: red;
}

.customcursor {
    cursor: url(http://media.fluke.com/images/8-icon-30x30.gif), default;
}
```

Here is a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e8mmfupy/7/).

However, this is giving me two issues.

First issue: While dragging, when the cursor moves onto the `body` element, the custom cursor is no longer in effect. However, when the cursor moves onto the html element, the custom cursor does work. Admittedly, this can be solved by adding a wrapper element, so the cursor is never on the `body`, but I'm still perplexed about why this is happening.

Second issue: After dragging for the first time, the cursor gets stuck with the custom cursor, even though the `.customcursor` class has been removed. This second issue can be solved if I add `.customcursor` class on the `start` and `stop` events of the draggable rather than on `mousedown` and `mouseup`, but I wanted the custom cursor on `mousedown` even if the draggable isn't moved.

If anyone has some insight into why these issues are occurring or good ways to fix them, I'd really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `!important` to the the `cursor` change:

```
.customcursor {
    cursor: url(http://media.fluke.com/images/8-icon-30x30.gif), default !important;
}
```

The body was being overrode by a direct element style:

```
element.style {
    cursor: auto;
}
```

Also, for some reason, the cursor is being left behind as a direct `style` even after the class is removed. Remove it with JavaScript or jQuery:

```
$(window).on("mouseup", function() {
    $("*").removeClass("customcursor");
    //document.body.style.cursor = "";
    $("body").css("cursor", "")
    console.log("mouseup");
})
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ntyuuqq2/

Comment: Ah, yea I see that direct element `style` leftover on `body` now. Any idea how it got there?

Comment: I'm guessing that `cursor` works little differently than other styles. Seems to attach it instead of reference the class. Probably because the `cursor` is most likely a property of the body.